# How to remove small shapes from an image?

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have this **image**:

[image]

I have the following **functions**:

```
void DrawPixel(int x, int y, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b);
void ReadPixel(GLint x, GLint y, unsigned char &r, unsigned char &g, unsigned char &b);
```

### Objective

Remove the small shapes of the image, there are 4 small shapes in the image, I want to remove them. One way to do this would be by how many red pixels each shape has, if one shape has less than 200 red pixels for example, I'll remove it from the image by painting it in black. This is just a form of solution that I imagined, if anyone has any other alternative it will be welcome.

### What I've tried

```
void RemoveLastNoises(){
    int x,y;
    int cont = 0;
    unsigned char r,g,b;
    int xAux;

    for(y=0;y<NewImage.SizeY()-0;y++){
        for(x=0;x<NewImage.SizeX()-0;x++){
            NewImage.ReadPixel(x,y,r,g,b);
            if(r == 255){
                cont = 0;
                while(r == 255){
                    NewImage.ReadPixel(x+cont,y,r,g,b);
                    cont = cont + 1;
                }
                if(cont < 300){
                    NewImage.DrawPixel(x,y,255,255,255);
                }
            }
            xAux = x;
            x = x+cont;
        }
        x = xAux;
    }
}
```

This works, but only counts how many red pixels it has in a row (x), I found it interesting to put it here as a reference. Anyway, any idea to remove the small shapes will be welcome.

**Note**:The larger shapes are not to be modified, the height and width of the image is larger, I decrease the dimensions for the question to be readable.

Comment: Have you tried morpholgical filters?

Comment: It sounds like a job for a k-d tree

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of nonlinear filters that are called morophological filters. 
They use "and" and "or" combination to create filter masks. 
What you need to do is implement a closing. OpenGL does not privde such functions thus, you have to write the code on your own. To do so you

1. If they are always red just use the red channel as grey-scale image
2. Create a binary image from the created image
3. Inverse the image from 2
4. Create a filter mask with '1's that is large enough to cover the small parts you want to rease
5. Do A Dilation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) on the image with the filter mask
6. Do an Erosion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)) on the image with the same filter mask or a slightly smaller one
7. Invert the image again

5 and 6 are describing a "Closing" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)